# Dynamic text color with image of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, text, colors

Wondering if it is possible to change the color of text depending on what image is in another div. The reason being I have text in a div on top of a slideshow, and for example a white image would need black text, then the image would change and a black image would need white text.

My extremely basic set up:

```
<div class="text">

 <p>Dynamic color change</p>

</div>


<div class="slideshow">

 <img src="images/black-image.jpg">
 <img src="images/white-image.jpg">

</div>
```

Comment: You can use a translucent black background for the text with color white. Or translucent white background for the text with color black. Example http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_transparency

Comment: I did think of doing this. It would be a last resort if it cannot be done, Thanks.

Comment: maybe you need this jquery plugin with some modification. `http://benhowdle.im/Adaptive-Backgrounds/`

Comment: are images in next div static or dynamic resources?

Comment: Images are dynamic, can be changed if the user wishes. Thanks bekt, i'll have a look at that option.

Comment: You could use `text-shadow` to create white text with black outline that would work on any background.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, just tried it but it doesn't look great...